# My Latest Password

Tags: calculation-puzzle, primes

-What is your password?- my niece asks me.

-It is a four digit number.

-I know that.

-It is divisible by precisely three primes.

-Tell me more.

-It has at least one common divisor greater than 1 with precisely eight of the other 23 4-digit numbers that can be formed with those very same digits.

-More.

-I was alive in that particular year.

A few hours later:

-Now I know!

**What is my password?**

Comment: A few hours? A 4 digit password can be brute-forced *by hand* faster than that :-)

Comment: @Bass She took a nap before working it out by hand!

Comment: @Bass it's been a few hours, where's the answer? ;)

Comment: @WhatsUp I have added additional information to make answer unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: with extra information provided by the OP, now we could say that the answer is

> 1976

and this also spoils a lower bound of the age of the OP, assuming he's not lying (:

Original answer:

---

I don't know what I'm missing, but here's what I got.

Clarifications:

- I assume that "the other 23 4-digit numbers" implies that the number consists of four different non-zero digits.
- I assume that "at least one common divisor" means "one common divisor greater than $1$".

With these assumptions, I got:

> $1435 = 5 \times 7 \times 41$
>
>  $1495 = 5 \times 13 \times 23$
>
>  $1976 = 2^3 \times 13 \times 19$
>
>  $2135 = 5 \times 7 \times 61$
>
>  $2431 = 11 \times 13 \times 17$
>
>  $3145 = 5 \times 17 \times 37$
>
>  $3196 = 2^2 \times 17 \times 47$
>
>  $3289 = 11 \times 13 \times 23$
>
>  $3514 = 2 \times 7 \times 251$
>
>  $3598 = 2 \times 7 \times 257$
>
>  $4697 = 7 \times 11 \times 61$
>
>  $5423 = 11 \times 17 \times 29$
>
>  $6149 = 11 \times 13 \times 43$
>
>  $6391 = 7 \times 11 \times 83$
>
>  $6475 = 5^2 \times 7 \times 37$
>
>  $6479 = 11 \times 19 \times 31$
>
>  $6935 = 5 \times 19 \times 73$
>
>  $7385 = 5 \times 7 \times 211$
>
>  $7469 = 7 \times 11 \times 97$
>
>  $7843 = 11 \times 23 \times 31$
>
>  $7931 = 7 \times 11 \times 103$
>
>  $8435 = 5 \times 7 \times 241$
>
>  $9361 = 11 \times 23 \times 37$
>
>  $9581 = 11 \times 13 \times 67$
>
>  $9823 = 11 \times 19 \times 47$
>
>  $9835 = 5 \times 7 \times 281$

And I don't see any information coming from the sentences of the niece (i.e. "I know that" and "Tell me more" don't give extra information here, as far as I can tell).

Thus I'm confused at this point.

Some analysis here:

> There are $1104$ numbers with four different non-zero digits that have three prime divisors.
>
>  Among them, we found the above $26$ solutions, which is about $1/42$ of all the $1104$ candidates.
>
>
>  This is still lower than a naive estimation of $1 / 24$ (assuming that the number of permutations with common divisors distributes uniformly in $\{0,1,\dots, 23\}$).
>
>
>  Thus it is quite reasonable to expect such a situation that we have many solutions. That is, if this is just a mathematical puzzle...

Comment: smh. I wrote a script to find this and could never identify the final number by the divisor rule because I didn't exclude 1...